# How does Application Insights ( and Live metrics stream) works internally?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, middleware, azure-application-insights

I have Application Insights configured for my AspNet Web API application. On this application I also have OAuth2 authentication :

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

In Live Metrics Stream I see some errors from OAuth middleware ( failed requests to /oauth2/token). But I cand found any requests to this url neither in ApplicationInsights Analytics nor using search on Azure portal. Why it happens?

Comment: Both channels (persistent and live) process the same stream of events. If you see different behavior the following factors can contribute: 1) app is very loaded & errors happen rarely. in this case regular channel might not catch such errors due to sampling. 2) regular channel populate Name based on heuristics. so it might not be /oauth2/token. Data field in Analytics should contain intact URL. Can you check whether you're hitting any of these?

Comment: @ZakiMa 1) Errors hannepns ~ 2-3ms . Application isn't very loaded.  2) Can you please explain, what you means in "regular channel populate Name based on heuristics" ? Maybe you can provide some links, where I can read about this? Thanks!  PS. My Live metrics stream and analytics query results looks like that: https://i.imgur.com/EHrPUT5.png  https://i.imgur.com/vjVeaUl.png

Comment: Can you please run the following query? requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| where resultCode == "400"
| order by timestamp 
| take 5

Comment: And maybe excluding other known 400 result codes?

Comment: @ZakiMa , it returns 2 requests, both of them from another actions ( from my web api controllers)

Comment: Is it possible to come up with a small repro and publish an issue on github (https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server)? As I mentioned both streams internally work on the same data stream, so data is expected to show up in both (live and analytics) places.

Comment: @ZakiMa I'm sorry for wasting your time, but it was bug in our code. Another developer made some changes in project, and this changes affected logging functionality :(

Comment: No worries. Glad to hear that it worked at the end! =)